# How to pass a boolean from fragment to adapter

Tags: java, android, kotlin, android-recyclerview, interface

I have this fragment in which I have a switch. What I want is that, when the switch's state is set to false, the items in the recycler view I have change color. The thing is, I am not sure how to pass the boolean from my fragment to my adapter. I was trying to do so through an interface but it doesn't seem to be working, the color is changed all the time, no matter the state of the switch.

This is the part in the fragment:

```
private Boolean switchState = false;

@Override
public boolean getClicked() {
    if(switchState) {
        return false;
    }
    return true;
}
```

The part in the adapter (after passing the interface to the class and everything):

```
interface ClickHere {
    val clicked: Boolean
}
//inside the viewholder that has the bind function
 if(clickHere.clicked){
    faceImage.alpha = 0.5F                     
    faceName.setTextColor(resources.getColor(R.color.disabled))
    } else {
      faceImage.alpha = 1F
      faceName.setTextColor(resources.getColor(R.color.content_1))
}
```

So far, the recycler seems to be functioning as if the clickHere.clicked is always true, no matter the switch. How can I make it listen to the boolean from my fragment?

Alternative with variable as suggested in comment but still not working:
Inside ViewHolder class and binding function.

```
var adapterVariable = myAdapter(listener,displayMetrics)
if(adapterVariable.colored{    
    faceImage.alpha = 0.5F                     
    faceName.setTextColor(resources.getColor(R.color.disabled))
    } else {
      faceImage.alpha = 1F
      faceName.setTextColor(resources.getColor(R.color.content_1))
}
```

In fragment:

```
myAdapter adapter = new myAdapter(this, getContext().getResources().getDisplayMetrics());
binding.facialSwitch.setOnClickListener(view -> {
    if(switchState){
        turnSwitchOff();
        adapter.setColored(switchState);
    } else {
        turnSwitchOn();
        adapter.setColored(false);
    }
});
```

Comment: Is your adapter used in the same fragment as the switch?
And are you calling 'notifyDataSetChanged' on your adapter, after toggling the color?

Comment: @luk321 yes, I use it there to show the recycler view

Comment: @Blundell my recyclerview works well, though, I just am not sure how to add this functionality so it will work

Comment: why are you using fragment in java and adapter in Kotlin? That is not preferred

Comment: @SambhavKhandelwal i know but it's not my own code, I just need to contribute to it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Inside of your adapter, you can instantiate a private boolean variable with a matching getter and setter function. This variable is then used inside your viewhholder creation. Make sure, that you're calling `notifyDataSetChanged` in your setter method. Otherwise, your items will not get redrawn and therefore will not update their color.

You can do that with:

```
var colored = false
    set(value) {
        field = value
        this.notifyDataSetChanged()
    }
```

After adding these, add a listener to your switch, which calls the adapters new set function. Make sure you save your adapter as a variable inside your fragment.

This is achieved with:

```
var adapter: MyAdapter // create in onCreateView, save in your fragment
var switch: Switch // get from your UI
switch.setOnCheckedChangeListener(CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener{ _, isChecked ->
        adapter.colored = isChecked})
```

By that, there is no interface needed.

Comment: your idea sounds great but it's not working for me. I pass adapter.setColored(true) since it's in java but it doesn't change color

Comment: My bad, don't set your color right inside of your ViewHolder class. Use the ´onBindViewHolder´ function to change your list views. Then you can access the adapter itself inside the function. In your code example, you're creating a new adapter, which does not link to the variable you're setting in your fragment.